# How to add or combine two columns into another one in a dataframe if they meet a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to this, so this may sound weird but basically, I have a large dataframe but for simplification purposes let's assume the dataframe is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfn = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'b':[6,7,8,9,10],
                   'c':np.nan})
dfn
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   6   NaN
1   2   7   NaN
2   3   8   NaN
3   4   9   NaN
4   5   10  NaN
```

What I want to do is to fill in values in the 'c' column based off of a condition, namely if the corresponding row value in 'a' is odd, then add it to the corresponding row value  'b' and input into 'c', else, just use the 'a' value for 'c'.

What I currently have is this:

```
for row in range(dfn.shape[0]):
    if dfn.loc[row]['a']%2!=0:
        dfn.loc[row]['c']=dfn.loc[row]['a']+dfn.loc[row]['b']
    else:
        dfn.loc[row]['c']=dfn.loc[row]['a']

dfn
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   6   NaN
1   2   7   NaN
2   3   8   NaN
3   4   9   NaN
4   5   10  NaN
```

Nothing seems to happen here and I'm not entirely sure why.

I've also tried a different approach of:

```
is_odd=dfn[dfn['a']%2!=0]
is_odd['c'] = is_odd['a'] + is+odd['b']

is_odd
```

Here, weirdly I get the right output:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   1   2
2   3   3   6
4   5   5   10
```

But when I call dfn again, it comes out with all NaN values.

I've also tried doing it without using a variable name and nothing happens.

Any idea what I'm missing or if there's a way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [numpy where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which works for conditionals. It is akin to an if statement in Python, but significantly faster. I rarely use `iterrows`, since I don't find it as efficient as numpy where.

```
 dfn['c'] = np.where(dfn['a']%2 !=0, 
                     dfn.a + dfn.b,
                     dfn.a)


    a   b   c
0   1   6   7
1   2   7   2
2   3   8   11
3   4   9   4
4   5   10  15
```

Basically, the first line in np.where defines your condition, which in this case is finding out if the 'a' column is an odd number. If it is, the next line is executed. If it is an even number, then the last line is executed. You can think of it as an if-else statement.

Comment: This worked out quite nicely; thanks! Didn't know about the np.where function so this it's nice to learn about :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.mod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mod.html) and [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to get a copy of column `b` with `0` **where** there is an even value in `a`, then  we add this serie to `a`.

```
dfn['c'] = dfn['b'].where(dfn['a'].mod(2).eq(1), 0).add(dfn['a'])
print(dfn)
   a   b   c
0  1   6   7
1  2   7   2
2  3   8  11
3  4   9   4
4  5  10  15
```

**Alternative**

```
dfn['c'] = dfn['a'].mask(dfn['a'].mod(2).eq(1), dfn['a'].add(dfn['b']))
```

Answer (score 0):

`dfn.loc[row]['c']=...` is always wrong. `dfn.loc[row]` may be either a copy or a view, so you cannot know what will happen. The *correct* way is:

```
dfn.loc[row, 'c']=...
```

Anyway here you should avoid the iteration and use `np.where` as suggested by other answers

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which is close to original thought of the author of the question, hope it can be helpful

```
def oddadd(x):
    if x['a']%2!=0:
        return x['a']+x['b']
    else:
        return x['a']
dfn["c"] = dfn.apply(oddadd,axis=1)
```